# Showing Uploaded Picture on Frontend

Tags: frontend

I am using Magento's file upload on the front end for customers to upload pictures.  When I get to the cart, it shows the product image and not the uploaded file.  What do I need to add to get the uploaded file to show instead of the generic product image?  Thanks.

Comment: can you please post an answer with how you solved the issue.

Comment: i will give extra bounty 100 points if this work for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways.

1) When you save image from front-end then it will added to the particular product image gallery and set this new image as a image ,thumb image so all places you got latest uploaded image.

2) The another way is that if you don't want to add in image gallery then create your custom module. Crate one table and store the product id,image name. When you required this product image then fetch from our table display over there.

Comment: Appreciate it. Since Magento doesn't store these images I have to add it to my own created tables?

Comment: Yes you have to store image in custom table.

Comment: You welcome. :) :)

Comment: @KeyulShah can you please update the answer with code.

Comment: This is not a right way if a user add the image from front-end and hold the product for 2 min before checkout process. within that 2 min if other user save the other image for that product then 2nd image will be show for first user.

Comment: @Ch037 if 1st user upload image, than it will display only for him instead of `product view page`, but these images will not replace in backend as `product image`  , please check [here](http://www.dailyobjects.com/custom-cases/letv/le1s-eco/custom-letv-le-1s-eco-cases/slim)