# Is there any Module to create text on product (tshirt), upload images on product

Tags: magento-1.9, php-5.4

I want to make a custom module to personalize products, such as add text on tshirt, upload images on products and then save it as final product.

I have searched many links, but all extensions are paid.

Comment: May be these links helpfull for you :  [link1](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12531/showing-uploaded-picture-on-frontend) 

 & [link2](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5571/is-there-any-free-extension-available-for-designing-products-label-or-cover-in-m/%22Here%22)

Comment: You don't need an extension for what you want to do. In the backend go to: Catalog -> Products. Choose existing product or New Product. On Product Page go to Custom Options. By the way: Paid extensions aren't necessarily useless, as you are suggesting.

Comment: I want the text what I write in textbox should be shown on products at the same time.

Comment: Quick and dirty way: Create a Static Block with your T-shirt desginer in it. Make sure that the Static Block is uploaded as Order Comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an extension for what you want to do.

In the backend go to:

Catalog -> Products.

Choose existing product or New Product.

On Product Page go to Custom Options.

By the way: Paid extensions aren't necessarily useless, as you are suggesting.

Comment: I want the text what I write in textbox should be shown on products at the same time.